# How to identify browser tab?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I would like to identify browser tabs (on my domain) using JavaScript.
I mean that if user open several tabs with my website and submit web form only on one page I want to notify only this page, even if user moves from this page.
It should be max cross browsers solution.

P.S. One of the possible solutions is using "window.name" property, but I do not want to use it because somebody else can use it.

P.S-2: I found one more possible solution: using [sessionStorage](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webstorage.html). It supported by FF3.5+, Chrome4+, Safari4+, Opera10.5+, and IE8+. Oooohhh, I need IE7!!!!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean? If a tab makes a request, the response will already go to that tab.

Comment: It's something I didn't try but: server can't push data to a browser, a request must be posted from the browser but you may use **Local Storage** (where available) to keep track of multiple pages (_secondary_ pages won't post any AJAX request to the server).

Comment: Dave Newton, we using cometd and there is a delay.

Comment: @DioNNiS for IE7 take a look to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424(VS.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sessionStorage. It supported by FF3.5+, Chrome4+, Safari4+, Opera10.5+, and IE8+.

For IE7 using "window.name" property.

Answer (score 2):

`window.name` is the only persistent data element you can use for this purpose, as described your requirements.

> I want to notify only this page, even if user moves from this page.

This is impossible. Once a user navigates away from a page, you lose control over that tab. You can't push to a page, it needs to make a server request FROM that page, even if it's ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done.  Each browser tab that is opened is basically like a new browser instance.  Just like if the user opened another browser.  One tab knows nothing about the other tab by design. This is how it should be.  Can you imagine the implications if a web site developer could add code to their page to "see" what other sites you have opened in your browser?